# Array de elementos em string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como transformar esse array object de `td's`

```
localidades = "<td style='white-space: nowrap;'>Sto.amaro</td><td style='white-space: nowrap;'>Osasco</td><td style='white-space: nowrap;'>Lapa</td><td style='white-space: nowrap;'>Osasco Ii</td><td style='white-space: nowrap;'>Sao Miguel</td><td style='white-space: nowrap;'>Pirituba</td><td style='white-space: nowrap;'>Santana</td>";
```

em seguida eu uso

```
console.log($(localidades).text(''));
```

e ele me retorna esse array abaixo

```
[<td style=​"white-space:​ nowrap;​">​​</td>​, <td style=​"white-space:​ nowrap;​">​​</td>​, <td style=​"white-space:​ nowrap;​">​​</td>​, <td style=​"white-space:​ nowrap;​">​​</td>​, <td style=​"white-space:​ nowrap;​">​​</td>​, <td style=​"white-space:​ nowrap;​">​​</td>​, <td style=​"white-space:​ nowrap;​">​​</td>​]
```

Gostaria de transformar esse array de volta para string só que com as tds vazias como na string abaixo

```
"<td style='white-space: nowrap;'></td><td style='white-space: nowrap;'></td><td style='white-space: nowrap;'></td><td style='white-space: nowrap;'></td><td style='white-space: nowrap;'></td><td style='white-space: nowrap;'></td><td style='white-space: nowrap;'></td>"
```

Comment: O primeiro array se quer é válido (afaik), portanto nem há como. A não ser que ele seja um array de referências a elementos do DOM. Procede?

Comment: Conseguiste resolver esta pergunta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar a função `.each` concatenando o HTML do elemento em uma variável:

```js
var $localidades = $("<td style='white-space: nowrap;'>Sto.amaro</td><td style='white-space: nowrap;'>Osasco</td><td style='white-space: nowrap;'>Lapa</td><td style='white-space: nowrap;'>Osasco Ii</td><td style='white-space: nowrap;'>Sao Miguel</td><td style='white-space: nowrap;'>Pirituba</td><td style='white-space: nowrap;'>Santana</td>");

$localidades.text('');

var html = "";
$localidades.each(function(i, elm) {
  html += elm.outerHTML;
});

$("#result").text(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Se o que queres é ter uma string com esses TDs vazios podes fazer assim para os esvaziar:

```
$(localidades).map(function(){
    this.innerHTML = '';
    return this;
});
```

mas depois precisas de um elemento fictício para ter esse HTML e poderes extrair numa string. Um exemplo seria:

```
var limpo = $(localidades).map(function () {
    this.innerHTML = '';
    return this;
});
var tr = $('<tr />').html(limpo);
alert(tr[0].innerHTML);
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2woqp6tu/